# Is it possible to change from i686 (32-bit) to x86_64 Linux without a complete reinstall?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

I just bought a new laptop and installed Fedora 14 on it. I now just noticed that I must have been very sloppy when selecting the download CD, because somehow I managed to install the 32-bit i686 version instead of the 64-bit x86_64.

Is there a way to change without wiping out the existing install and do a reinstall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way that I am aware of, although it is possible with [**some work**](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/123800). By doing a reinstall you have the advantage of having 64-bit software ready at your fingertips, without worrying about compatibility issues. I would recommend the backup and reinstall route, but it's up to you.

Comment: I discussed this exact scenario on the Fedora forums last year and the general opinion was 'It's doable, but if you value your time and sanity, wipe and reinstall is the way to go'.

Comment: "no easy way" -- yep. I ended up having to use a Knoppix disc as a rescue boot a *couple* times before I got it right.

Comment: For sure. The author of the article admits to spending the better part of a **day** on the upgrade in the conclusion.

Comment: Since it is a new pc, there is (still) plenty of free space, so at first I will make a parallel installation.